# Add a custom field to django-watson

Tags: django, django-signals

I want to include a custom field in the watson model SearchEntry as almost all my searches will include it.

I've created a custom engine that creates a new field and index on install and linked to in settings:

```
   WATSON_BACKEND = "tools.custombackend.SearchBackend"
```

I can see how I am going to include it in the search by creating a custom SearchAdapter that is setup with I register the models.

However, I can't work out how to get my value into the model.  I thought I could use signals, but it's never getting triggered.

This is signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, pre_delete, post_save, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings
from watson.models import SearchEntry

@receiver(post_save, sender=SearchEntry)
def model_post_save(sender, **kwargs):
    never gets here....
```

and I'm calling it from one of the apps.py that I know is getting triggered.

```
class ToolsAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "tools"
    def ready(self):
        print 'loading signals'
        import tools.signals
```

Have I setup the signal receiver incorrectly? 
Maybe there is a better way?  The value I want to save in searchentry is in the object being indexed.

Comment: Are you sure SearchEntry.post_save is being sent?

Comment: I thought post_save was automatically sent by django?  Do you know how I would check that the signal is being sent?

Comment: They can not be. If save is overwritten, for instance, and doesn't call the parent classes 'save' then it won't send a signal. Could you expand on where you're saving a SearchEntry?